# Failed to Install - Google Cloud SDK for python on Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, windows-10, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I can't seem to understand why this just wouldn't install, it keeps failing and I have no idea how to proceed. Does anyone have any ideas as to why the installer would behave this way ?

Here is the bug filed at Google's Issue Tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37366016

Greatly appreciate any help :)

[image: Install Error]

[image: cmd prompt]

Comment: Which package (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned) you've downloaded and tried to install?

Comment: Check if you have any environmental variable that starts with "cloud" prefix: in a command line, check the output of `set cloud` and add it to the question. Check the PATH env variable as well for anything suspicious as well (run `set path`)

Comment: @JL-HN - this is for the x86_64 python bundle , any ideas on how I may proceed to fix it ?

Comment: @Valentin - done, however I'm not sure what to make of the results

Comment: I think this is a problem with the current Cloud SDK Windows installer and the 64 bit bundled python. You can try using the 32 bit tarball installation method, or skip the "bundled python" component item when installing. You seem to already have python installed so gcloud will just use that one.

Comment: Possibly related https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37289228 Please file a new issue if it's not. This way the Cloud SDK team can investigate.

Comment: @Valentin - tried that as well but it was unsuccessful, I commented on that thread but that suggested workaround didn't work for me either. Perhaps I could try the older GUI for App Engine that is no longer supported.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about this. I think you have a different problem. Mind filing a different bug so we can keep track of it?

Comment: In your case, I think you can use the versioned archive method at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned Once you download it, instead of running .\google-cloud-sdk\install.bat, open the file in an editor and remove the line "echo %CmdCmdLine% | find /i "%~0" >nul". Then you can run install.bat and finish the installation.
Please still file a bug so we can keep track of this.

Comment: @Valentin - thank you ! .. It seemed to have worked this time, I filed a bug like you requested :) cheers

Comment: I get the same error, and changing the bat file doesn't help. Set Cloud is empty, what should it be? Hard to believe this is from google, I was considering moving from AWS and this is my first experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments on this Q&A, the issue derives from a line in the installer which needs to be removed. The original comment by user "Valentin":

> In your case, I think you can use the versioned archive method at
>   [cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned](http://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned) Once you download it, instead
>   of running .\google-cloud-sdk\install.bat, open the file in an editor
>   and remove the line "`echo %CmdCmdLine% | find /i "%~0" >nul`". Then you
>   can run install.bat and finish the installation. Please still file a
>   bug so we can keep track of this.

OP noted that they filed an issue, so this is the appropriate resolution for anyone who sees this. I'd only request that OP update this thread with a link to their issue so other users can find it and watch for progress if they're interested.